# How to change a bot's cookie?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need a way to modify a bot cookie, its for auto login the bot whit a account, cause ever i restart my bot it has to login and i want it automatic, Thanks!, i made it whit node.js.

```
var express      = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log('Cookies: ', req.cookies);
});
app.listen(8080);
res.clearcookie('Cookie1');
res.clearcookie('Cookie2');
res.cookie('Cookie1', '1', { maxAge: 9000000000, httpOnly: true });
res.cookie('Cookie2', '2', { maxAge: 9000000000, httpOnly: true });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cookie belongs to a particular client, not to a server.

If you're a server listening to requests from clients, you can set cookies for the requesting client when they make a request of your server (you return the cookie as part of the response).

If you're node.js app is acting as a client and making requests to other servers, then you need to create what is often called a "cookie jar" so you (as the client) can keep track of cookies that you want sent to a particular host as part of each request to that host (you are simulating what a browser does with cookies in this regard since you are the client).  Once you create a cookie jar and use a request function that supports it (the `request` module is one such module), then you can set whatever cookies you want in the cookie jar and they will be sent with each request that you attach the cookie jar to.

The code you show in your question does not really make sense because you're trying to use `res` outside of any given request.  The `response` object only exists during a request, not in the top level scope.